# Class Not Found Error when loading classes within namespaces in a php file

Tags: php

I am trying to reference a namespaced php class from another php file but I keep getting class not found error. Here is what I have so far in a file named `RouterOSClient.php`

```
<?php

namespace RouterOS;

use RouterOS\Config;
use RouterOS\Client;

class RouterOSClient
{
    private $client;

    public function __construct(string $host, string $user, string $password)
    {
        $config = (new Config())
            ->set('timeout', 1)
            ->set('host', $host)
            ->set('user', $user)
            ->set('pass', $password);

        // Initiate client with config object
        $local_client = new Client($config);
        $this->client = $local_client;
    }

    public function get(): Client
    {
        return $this->client;
    }
}
```

Now I tried to create a new instance of the above class in another php file called `test.php` as below

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<span>Welcome</span>
<?php
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    use RouterOS\RouterOSClient;
    use RouterOS\Query;

    $routerOSClient = new RouterOSClient("127.0.0.1", "admin", "password");
    $client = $routerOSClient->get();
    $query = new Query('/interface/bridge/host/print');
    $response = $client->query($query)->read();
    print_r($response);

    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Surprisingly I keep getting this error whenever I run `test.php` on the browser.

```
Uncaught Error: Class &quot;RouterOS\RouterOSClient&quot; not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\AppName\test.php:12
Stack trace:
```

My `composer.json` file is:

```
{
    "require": {
        "divineomega/php-ssh-connection": "^2.2"
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Is RouterOS your code or a composer library? Post the relevant part of your composer.json please. And what is the directory structure? Is test.php in the same dir as RouterOS/RouterOSClient.php?

Comment: Hi, perhaps a directory location issue?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `RouterOS` is not a composer library `RouterOS` is the namespace under which `RouterOSClient` is packaged. It's just the name I gave it. `RouterOSClient` is not in a directory...It sits on same directory as my other html files. Yes, `test.php` is in the same directory as `RouterOSClient.php`

Comment: You need to provide the autoload section of your composer.json to check that RouterOS namespace resolves in the right directory. You also need to run composer dump-autoload at least once to configure autoloader.

Comment: So your composer.json has no `autoload` section? You will probably need `"autoload": { "psr-4": { "RouterOS\\": "" } }` assuming composer.json is in the same dir as test.php